# Is there a Chinese variant of the expression "and the list goes on and on“

Tags: translation, phrase

Is there a Chinese variant of the expression "and the list goes on and on" or something simillar to it?

Comment: suggestion：submit "on and on, w/o end" to online dictionaries, iciba:没完没了 méiwán méiliǎo, now submit 没完没了 to bkrs: used attributively: 没完没了的痛苦, adverbially: 没完没了地打电话, as complement:那两个女人叽里咕噜说个没完没了, also iciba: go on without end 无止境地继续下去, users suggest 清单、名单无止境地继续下去个没完没了

Comment: @user6065 I don't think 没完没了 quite fits in here. Because it has a "annoying" connotation, like when you describe an unpleasant thing that continues forever and won't stop. On the other side, "the list goes on" is used when you're enumerating items, which should be neutral.

Answer (score 3):

There might be many expressions in different cases. The most common one should be:
等 or 等等： etc.; and so on
那里有很多气球，红色、橙色、绿色、蓝色、白色等等，各种颜色。

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the common 等等, it seems like 诸如此类 and 诸如...之类 match your request. Native speakers, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

There's a 成语 expressing this meaning：不胜枚举

Comment: 不胜枚举 means "too many to pointing out one by one"